DartError: Unsupported operation: Platform._version Creacion de Carpeta en Drive con cuenta de servicio
tengo un problema, necesito poder crear una carpeta con una cuenta de servicios que ya esta en Google Cloud Console (GCC para abreviarlo despues), y me da el error de

DartError: Unsupported operation: Platform._version

el error me lo da en la siguiente linea
final httpClient = IOClient(HttpClient());

No se cual sea el error ya que en el json vienen todas las configuraciones que crea GCC automaticamente, alguien que me pueda ayudar con esto
Adjunto el codigo completo
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as drive;
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/googleapis_auth.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:io';

class PruebaCarpeta extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PruebaCarpetaState createState() => _PruebaCarpetaState();
}

class _PruebaCarpetaState extends State<PruebaCarpeta> {
  drive.DriveApi? _driveApi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeDriveApi();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeDriveApi() async {
    // Carga las credenciales de la cuenta de servicio desde el archivo JSON
    final credentialsJson = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/Assets/credentials.json');

    final serviceAccountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(
        json.decode(credentialsJson)
    );

    final httpClient = IOClient(HttpClient());

    // Obtén un cliente autenticado usando las credenciales de la cuenta de servicio
    final authClient = await clientViaServiceAccount(
      serviceAccountCredentials,
      [drive.DriveApi.driveScope],
      baseClient: httpClient,
    );

    setState(() {
      _driveApi = drive.DriveApi(authClient);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _crearCarpetaEnDrive() async {
    if (_driveApi == null) {
      print('Google Drive API no está inicializada');
      return;
    }

    final folder = drive.File();
    folder.name = "Carpeta del curso ";
    folder.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

    // Especifica el ID de la carpeta "padre" aquí
    folder.parents = ["0APPs7XyaRSsbUk9PVA"]; // Reemplaza con el ID correcto

    try {
      final folderResponse = await _driveApi!.files.create(folder);
      print('Carpeta creada con éxito en Drive: ${folderResponse.id}');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creando carpeta: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Crear Carpeta en Google Drive'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _crearCarpetaEnDrive,
              child: Text('Crear Carpeta en Drive'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Que es lo que debe de pasar, ahorita es una prueba, pero lo que debe de pasar es que cualquier usuario pueda crear su propia carpeta, pero como no todos tienen acceso a algunas carpetas que usare por seguridad, necesito que la cuenta de servicios que si tiene accesso, pueda crear la carpeta, ya en mi base de datos, queda el registro del usuario que la creo.
Todo esto es una app web y estoy usando google chrome
